# How to work with auto incrementing columns in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

how would I use the insert into syntax with mysql columns that are auto incrementing?

for example:

```
INSERT INTO table (auto, firstname, lastname) VALUES ('Dan','Davidson')
```

would the above code work and fill in the columns firstname and lastname while having auto auto-increment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to list the auto-incrementing column in the field list, it will auto-increment regardless:

`INSERT INTO table (firstname, lastname) VALUES('Dan', 'Davidson')`

Comment: Using `NULL` or `DEFAULT` should work in the VALUES section if the autoincrement column is included in the list of columns.

Comment: @OMG Ponies point is worth noting if you have a case where your table has many columns, all of which need updating, except one, which is an autoincrement column. In that case, instead of typing out all the column names, you can just pass `NULL` to the autoincrement column.

Answer (score 3):

No, the code would not work. The auto-increment column should not be inserted to as the value is dynamically generated. Doing the following:

```
INSERT INTO table (firstname, lastname) VALUES ("fName", "lName")
```

Will automatically assign a vlue to the "auto" field.

Answer (score 1):

You can just leave that field null.

```
INSERT INTO table (auto, firstname, lastname) VALUES (null, 'Dan','Davidson')
```

or just leave the auto incrementing field out.

```
INSERT INTO table (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('Dan','Davidson')
```